# How to achieve bright lighting during sunset

Tags: lighting, sunset

I found this below image with a beautiful lighting. This actually is photographed during sunset. But, how the photographer is able to achieve such bright and gold type lighting?

**Source:** [from 500px.com](https://500px.com/photo/144079857/marundeeswarar-temple-chennai-by-kicha-)

[image: Bright Sunset]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty much all post-processing. Search for internet articles using the terms *tone mapping*, *exposure fusion*, *noise reduction*, and *HDR*.

Comment: Hey, you can find this article by googling *technicolor vomit rainbows*: http://www.peterstewartphotography.com/Blog/I-Hate-Photomatix

Comment: Great article. Also can I know few interesting articles on `exposure fusion` and `tone mapping`?